# Issue with Ajax scriptmanager giving a 404 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Im having an issue with the scriptmanager for ajaxtoolkit its giving a 404 error.

default.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.5.51116.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3a2a06c7e2-728e-4b15-83d6-9b269fb7261e%3a475a4ef5%3a5546a2b%3ad2e10b12%3aeffe2a26%3a37e2e5c9%3a5a682656%3a12bbc599

this is giving a 404 error but default.asp file is showing fine

Answer (score 0):

the 404 is because the Url is too long and is rejected by the web server.  Though the page may look fine generally, the Ajax controls will not work properly.

If your web server is on .NET Framework 4.0 or later you can overcome the error by adding the following section to the <system.webServer> element in your web.config:

```
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="5000" />
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```